# Ionic - Page content is outside screen when moving between states

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using ionic on android, and when I use `$state.go()`, the new view is much wider than the screen, and I get a horizontal scrollbar on the bottom. When I scroll the view, all I see is white content.

When I press the back button, I get blank page, much wider than the screen.
the wierdest thing is that when I inspect the white page, all the html element are located on the white part of the view, but i can see the content of the page in the edge of the view (after Im scrolling the view horizontally).

Can someone pls help me fix this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure but probably you need:

```
<ion-content has-header="true" padding="false" overflow-scroll="false">
```